# ASP.NET webforms - Modifying control CSS depending on validator type in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I want to  distinguish between required field validators and regular expression validators in my Javascript code so I can change the background color of my controls depending on the validator. Any idea how can I do it?
EDIT :
this is the script that i want to modify ( add a condition depending on required validators or regular expression validators)
[image: Script]

Comment: Its doable, please provide more details. Piece of Client side markup with those different controls would give more insight to give suggestions :)

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using client-side jQuery validation, which is the default in new ASP.NET MVC and Webforms projects, then you already have the attributes you need in HTML.

For example take a look at the following code in ASP.NET Webforms:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Email" />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The email field is required." />

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The email is not valid" />
</div>
```

This code produces a textbox input field and two sibling **span** HTML elements for the validators with corresponding `data attributes` that identify the validator type, the validation function to execute etc.

So the output for the required validator is:

```
<span data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val-initialvalue=""  data-val="true" data-val-errormessage="The email field is required." data-val-controltovalidate="MainContent_Email"></span>
```

and for a regex validator it is:

```
<span data-val-evaluationfunction="RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val="true" data-val-errormessage="The email field is required." data-val-controltovalidate="MainContent_Email"></span>
```

I have omitted some of output details for simplicity.

So you can just use the existing data attributes that ASP.NET outputs and interpret them in your javascript code.

In fact **the Page_Validators array contains that data already**. So you can do something like this:

```
switch(Page_Validators[i].evaluationfunction.name){
    case "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid": 
        // do stuff for required field validators
        break;
    case "CustomValidatorEvaluateIsValid": 
        // do stuff for custom validators
        break;
    case "RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid": 
        // do stuff for regex validators
        break;
    case "CompareValidatorEvaluateIsValid": 
        // do stuff for compare validators          
        break;
}
```

Comment: so if i want to get the required field validators , i should use : `PageValidatoes[i].attr('data-val-required')` ? does it work?

Comment: Check out the switch example.